# access resources from another apk for widget (like theme apk)

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, android-resources, android-appwidget

I made a theme with drawables and strings, I can access the theme's resources by following commands

```
String packagename="com.....";
Resources res = context.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(packagename);
int strid = res.getIdentifier(packagename+":string/"+name, "string", packagename);
int drawableid = res.getIdentifier(packagename+":drawable/"+name, "drawable", packagename);

String name = res.getString(resid);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resid);
//or
Drawable dr=res.getDrawable(resid);
```

I can get the drawables, but I don't know how to set the drawables in xml to a widget.
I only can set `setImageViewResource(int viewid, int resId);`

**So I am asking that how to access xml resources from another apk and set widget drawables from it.**

I want to access a resource like this from another theme apk, but I can only access the drawable (so can't use it for widgets)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/wplayh" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wplay" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a ContentProvider to share your app's data with another apps

Comment: I already got the application resources from another apk(so i don't need content provider), but i am unable to use them on a widget, i mean in a xml drawable selector as mentioned in above xml code.